# visual studio and SSMS flash and close instantly when openned

Tags: crash, debug, visual-studio-2015, ssms

Yesterday I was working normally, left work with my computer open by simply locking it.

Today I come in and it's shutdown so I power it up, boots properly.

I try to start my workday by openning visual studio and SSMS but they don't open anymore, they simply flash the loading box and close as pictured :
[image]

It doesn't give me any errors, I looked in windows Event Viewer and nothing seems to correlate on the time the app fails to open.

I tried :

-repairing .net (I already have 4.7 installed)

-repairing visual studio

-currently trying to repair SSMS

-Uninstalling yesterday's windows security update

-re-installing yesterday's windows security update

Any idea what I should try next ?

Comment: have you checked task manager/process explorer to make sure they're not running, just not visible?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't show up:  https://i.imgur.com/u2gnVy1.gif

Comment: I ended up just formatting my computer.